# How so separate a string and order each record by left number in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, sorting, pointers

I have a file.csv . it contains two numbers separated by a comma.I put every line , such as string, in a pointer of char `char *arr`. My aim is to sort in ascending order by left number (number before comma i.e. //this is the example of what I have to sort, the whole example is below:
9514902
1134289
7070279
ecc..)
I tried `strtok()`  but it delete the number after comma. I need both of the numbers for each couple.
To order the numbers I used *Insertion Sort*, trasforming my strings (couple of numbers with comma for me is a string) in long integers in order to compare them. `swap` function doesn't work because it returns me numbers that I've never passed him.
How can I resolve it?

**main.c**

```
#define SIZE 10 
#define LEN 20

void swap(char *xp, char *yp){
    char *temp=xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = *temp;
}

int main(){

    FILE *fd = NULL;
    fd = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    int pos=0;
    char (*arr)[LEN] = NULL;  
    arr = calloc ( SIZE, sizeof *arr);
    while ( pos < SIZE && fgets ( arr[pos], sizeof arr[pos], fd)) {
        ++pos;
    }
   
    int i, j;
    char *ptr;
    for (i = 1; i < SIZE; i++){
        char *p = strtok(arr[i], ",");
        long pivot= strtol(p,&ptr,10);
        char * c = strtok(arr[i-1], ",");
        long value= strtol(c,&ptr,10);

        for (j = i - 1; (j >= 0) && (value>pivot); j--){ 
            swap(arr[j],arr[j+1]);
            j--;
            c = strtok(arr[j], ",");
            value= strtol(c,&ptr,10);
        }
    }
}
```

**file.csv**

```
9514902,846
1134289,572
7070279,994
30886,48552
750704,1169
1385812,729
471548,3595
8908491,196
4915590,362
375309,212
```

Comment: The functioon `swap()` should be `char temp=*xp; *xp = *yp; *yp = temp;`

Comment: It doesn't work..When it get the swap function it does nothing @WeatherVane

Comment: Ah, if you are trying to swap two pointers, you need double-stars, and to pass the address of the pointer. It would be easier to do it in-place. A swap barely warrants a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `strtok` too, Maybe this is not you looking for but you can look as another way of doing what you want, **Have Fun**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE* pFile = fopen("file.csv", "r");

    if(pFile == NULL)
        return 1;

    char aBuf[256];
    char aResult[1024];
    aResult[0] = '\0';

    // get each line
    for(int i=0; fgets(aBuf, sizeof(aBuf), pFile) != NULL; i++){
        // find comma in line
        for(int j=0; j < strlen(aBuf); j++){
            if(aBuf[j] != ',')
                continue;

            // copy everything before comma
            char aAnotherBuffer[50];
            strncpy(aAnotherBuffer, aBuf, j);

            // convert it to integer
            int FirstNum = atoi(aAnotherBuffer);

            // get after of comma and convert it too
            int SecondNum = atoi(aBuf + j + 1);

            // make line that with sorted values
            char aRes[256];
            sprintf(aRes, 
                "%d,%d\n",
                FirstNum < SecondNum? FirstNum: SecondNum,
                FirstNum > SecondNum? FirstNum: SecondNum
            );
            // concatenate to result buffer 
            strcat(aResult, aRes);

            // go for next line
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(pFile);


    // save results
    {
        FILE* pResFile = fopen("result.csv", "w");

        if(pResFile){
            fputs(aResult, pResFile);
            fclose(pResFile);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```